# Converting one string with multiple lists/arrays into separate lists

Tags: python, xml, elementtree, plaintext

The title is terrible. This is what I mean. I'm using Wolfram|Alpha's API. And while parsing it, I get these god-awful strings, like this (by querying "spider-man"):

> "year | title | medium 1962 | Amazing Fantasy #15 | comic book 1967 | Spider-Man | animation > 1977 | The Amazing Spider-Man | television 1978 | Questprobe #2 Spider-Man | video game 2002 > | Spider-Man | movie"

And this is actually a string representation of what should be lists like this():

> [year, title, medium]
>
> [1962, Amazing Fantasy #15, comic book]
>
> [1967, Spider-Man, video game]
>
> [2002, Spider-Man, movie]

I can easily split this into one big list...but I can't think of a simple way to get them into the lists like they should be (shown above). Any suggestions other than converting to a big list, parsing the list, separating them into a list of lists by creating a a new list every 3rd item I iterate through...?

ex of my idea (long way):

```
listA = list()
listA = textRepresentation.split("|")
listB = list()
listC = list()
i = 1
for item in listA:
  if(i == 3):
    listB.append(listC)
    i = 1
  else:
    listC.append(item)
    i++
```

Comment: I'm not sure you can separate "medium" from "1962" automatically.

Comment: How about using `csv` module with specific to ur case `lineterminator` and `delimiter`? See http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#dialects-and-formatting-parameters.

Comment: @wRAR Your absolutely right. I just realized that a few minutes ago after implementing my mock code. I kept thinking they were using two different version of "|" and one wasn't being "separated"... -.-

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import re
zip(*[(i.strip() for i in re.split('(\d{4})|\||>', text) if i and i.strip())]*3)
```

out:

```
[('year', 'title', 'medium'),
 ('1962', 'Amazing Fantasy #15', 'comic book'),
 ('1967', 'Spider-Man', 'animation'),
 ('1977', 'The Amazing Spider-Man', 'television'),
 ('1978', 'Questprobe #2 Spider-Man', 'video game'),
 ('2002', 'Spider-Man', 'movie')]
```

Comment: Thank you. Still figuring out how it works so I can use this method again (I know it's regular expression, but I'm not well versed using them). You're a miracle worker! Thanks again!

Comment: What if i have two items for each list, but the second item may or may not contain multiple items separated by new lines? For example: sex|male family: uncle ben (uncle) (newline) aunt may (aunt)

Comment: For example: sex|male family: uncle ben (uncle) (newline) aunt may (aunt) (newline) ... etc ...

Comment: @jpcguy89 -- at the moment it is hard to understand how your example fits with the data sample in your question. you may edit your question with an updated sample and I will try to take a look.

Comment: I think I figured it out. (I ran into another section of my data that had multiple items separated by new lines for (using the example I gave) 'year', 'title', and/or 'medium'.

Using [link](http://www.gskinner.com/regexr) as a reference to the different parts of a regular expression, and your answer as guidance, I came up with:

    self.goodText = zip(*[(i.strip() for i in re.split('(\n*)|\||>', att.text) if i and i.strip())]*3)

Comment: I then managed to fix any issues with the regular expression through basic python code fairly easily.